# Create Map of Map using JSON Schema in AWS API Model

Tags: aws-api-gateway

I want to create a Map variable in the SDK - AWS API - for which I need to write a JSON Schema Input / Output Model.

Help me write JSON Schema syntax such that I can achieve my objective

Answer (score 1):

To just make one Map variable -

```
{
  "type" : "object",
  "required" : [ "answers" ],
  "properties" : {
    "answers" : {
      "type" : "object",
       "additionalProperties": { "type": "string" }
    }
  },
  "title" : "test"
}
```

to Create a Map of Map use:

```
"answers": {
         "type" :"object",
         "additionalProperties" : 
            {   "type" : "object",
                "additionalProperties" : {"type" : "string"}
             }
}
```